# small cherry tree has gum leaking, probably wound

Tags: trees, plant-health, cherries

I have a small cherry tree that has some glue leaking, think it might have a wound that I didn't notice before, probably from when it snowed in spring last year.
There are also some yellow leaves on a branch.

photo of the wound/glue:
[image: tree wound]

photo of the whole tree: 
[image: whole tree]
is there something that I could do to help it, or the tree will heal by itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not 'heal' at all - this is gummosis, which occurs for various reasons and is common in cherry trees. Likely the cold weather caused a fracture in the trunk/bark and this is the result. Sometimes, bacteria invades the area and then the exudate gets very unpleasant smelling, by which time its usually too late to save the tree. At this stage, you might be able to prevent it getting worse though; this link https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/fegen/what-is-gummosis.htm suggests stripping back the bark to healthy bark. Otherwise, there is no treatment I'm afraid.

Comment: we cut the top of the tree in 2018, under the wound, the tree is doing fine now

Comment: I  hesitated to suggest that! Had it been mine, I'd have risked it, but sometimes cutting it back so much can trigger lots of growth off the rootstock at ground level, or, more important, if the graft is at the top of the trunk and not the base, you end up cutting off the grafted part, which you don't want to do. Glad it worked though....

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is bacterial canker which  can affect cherries. That’s what we call it in the UK. There is no cure. Further more, you need to get rid of the tree carefully and burnt it to destroy the bacteria. Otherwise it will affect other trees in the area, especially if you have plums or other cherries.

Comment: actually there are 2 big (10+ years, 3 times taller) plum trees right behind me when I'm taking the picture, they aren't affected at all, some people suggested to cut the tree right below the wound and that this way it grow back in 1+ years/ regenerate, think I will use some branches for grafting on other trees before trying anything